# How long would it take a computer to check that a number is not divisible by any 20-digit prime?

Tags: number-theory, sieve-theory

If a computer could perform 10^18 division operations per second, how long would it take to check that a given number is not divisible by any 20-digit prime?

So I think I'm supposed to use trial division with the sieve of eratosthenes to figure out the number of 25 digit primes, but I'm absolutely lost. There are no resources online that give me a similar example. Can someone please help even put me in the right direction?

Comment: 20 or 25 digits?  Both appear in your question.  Also, do you have an estimate for how many 20- (or 25-) digit primes there are?

Comment: You can use the prime number theorem to estimate the number of primes of a given length.  That will be quite accurate enough.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! I am not sure whether the exact number of $25$-digit primes is known (might be the case). As mentioned, the prime number theorem gives a very good approximation. To check, whether a number is divisble by any $20$-digit prime, we can (at least with high probability of a correct result) apply the elliptic-curve method. This method is far mor efficient than trial division, but there is no guarantee to find all factors upto a given range. But we can run enough curves to have sufficient probability.

Comment: @Peter: The number of 25-digit primes is known.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function